# Subversion Native Library Not Avalible

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Buen día. De vez en cuando en mi [spring-tool-suite](/questions/tagged/spring-tool-suite) me sale una ventana que me indica que el plugin [subclipse](/questions/tagged/subclipse) no tiene acceso a las librerías nativas.

[image: Ventana de error]

En la parte de errores dice lo siguiente

> Failed to load JavaHL Library.
>
> These are the errors that were encountered:
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\ssleay32.dll: El sistema operativo no puede ejecutar %1
>   Native Library C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll already loaded in another classloader
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvn_delta-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvn_diff-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvn_wc-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvn_fs-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvn_repos-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvn_ra-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvn_client-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> C:\spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.3.SR1\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.15\libsvnjavahl-1.dll: No se encontró el proceso especificado
>
> no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
>
> no svnjavahl in java.library.path
>
> java.library.path = C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\app\INE\product\11.2.0\client_1;c:\ruby\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro\;C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\ASUS\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ASUS\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;;.

**Detalles de mi sistema:**

- intel core i7
- windows 8.1 pro
- sistema operativo 64 bits, procesador x64
- mi STS corre en un jdk 1.7.0_79

### ACTUALIZACIÓN

Parece ser que si tengo JavaHL Instalado.
[image: JavaHL]

De momento no me ha presentado problemas pero quisiera saber si podría tenerlos y si conocen una solución para que no mnde ese error.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: acabo de ver tu actualización, un poco raro tal vez necesites una actualización, podrías como prueba tratar con SVNKit, yo lo uso.

Comment: Normalmente el error me salía al abrir el IDE o al sincronizar, al cambiarle al SVNKit ya no sale, se me hacía raro porque era una nueva instalación. Gracias probaré a actualizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que no tienes `JavaHL` instalado:

```
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
```

Revisa en `Preferencias`, que tienes dentro de `SVN Interface`, trata cambiando a `SVNKit` (`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Team` -> `SVN`).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me aparece que si lo tengo instalado. Intentaré de todas formas hacer lo que me dices. Gracias por tu tiempo.